# React call function inside itself

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to call an arrow function inside itself in React.

I am fetching an api but if api response with status code 401, I do some things (that work as expect) and then I need to reexecute the function tokenGet. How can I do this? I tried this way below and with `return tokenGet(url);` and all ways result on a infinite loop on api.

```
const tokenGet = (url) => {
    const data = {
      ...
    };
    return fetch(url, data)
      .then(res => {
        if (res.status === 401) {
          ...
          tokenGet(url);
        } else {
          return res.json();
        }
      });
  };
```

I am calling above function this way on another component.

```
useEffect(() => {
    tokenGet(url)
      .then(data => {
        ...
      });
  }, []);
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance api will return 401 if access token expires. then I generate a new one, an reexecute the function. I believed that info wouldn't be important than I omit it

Comment: @CertainPerformance is this important to my question? the token is correctly generated inside the if and I can access it. what i can't do is reexecute the function tokenGet.

Comment: If the API is always returning 401, this will run infinitely. Make sure that API is returning something other than 401 once in a while.

Comment: @CertainPerformance oh no, I'm not even using state on this function. I just call a method from my api, and the results I store on localStorage. I can log my new token inside the if.

Comment: The answer is way too simple to warrant an actual answer so I'm just going to comment. It feels to me like this question is either just a typo or an unimportant misunderstanding of the language that has been answered hundreds of times before in hundreds of other questions. So here's the solution: `return tokenGet(url);` -- you need to return the Promise